# json objects from registry.nodejs.org shows error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, jsonp, bower

how can i use jsonP to get all the NPM packages that contain a keyword.
I used

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=["Keyword"]&&endkey=["keyword",{}]&group_level=3
```

and it throws an error that : is unexpected in console.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you provide more details by editing your answer. We need to know what you have tried and how you have tried it in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct search query is:

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=[%22keyword%22]&endkey=[%22keyword%22,{}]&group_level=3
```

You need to use **"keyword"** instead of **"Keyword"** and **'&'** instead of **'&&'**

Comment: Still i am getting same error the code is below
.factory('npmservice',function($http){
    var req=function(uname){
        return $http({
            method:'JSONP',
            url:'https://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=["'+uname+'"]&endkey=["'+uname+'",{}]&group_level=3'
            //https://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=["'+uname+'"]&endkey=["'+uname+'",{}]&group_level=3
        })
    };

Comment: U should add `startkey=["uname"]` and not `startkey=["%27+uname+%27"]` browser will convert it automatically

Comment: see i have done it
https://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=["keyword"]&endkey=["keyword",{}]&group_level=3
still it throws error

Comment: Your Url look like where u have missed end bracket (]) `https://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=[%22%27+uname+%27%22]&endkey=[%22%27+uname+%27%22` it should be `https://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=[%22%27uname%27%22]&endkey=[%22%27uname%27%22]`

Comment: my error comes when the json object is about to load and the token: is shown as error at starting